# Amplitude Analytics in Flutter

Tags: flutter, amplitude-analytics

How can I Integrate Amplitude Analytics in Flutter? I have to perform number of Analysis of my App using  Amplitude Analytics For example: I have to see how many Sign Ups are done of my App.I am having no idea regarding the implementation of Amplitude Analytics in Flutter please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's the late answer but please check the "amplitude_flutter" package.
Our team uses amplitude analytics for more than 1 year.
It's very stable now and provides a lot of information.

These are links for packages and repository.
https://pub.dev/packages/amplitude_flutter
https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Did you check with their support team on if they have flutter SDK?
If they don't have, as an alternate you can try add the SDK in the native platforms and add utility functions to send the events data using the platform channels.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Segment + Amplitude, you can add https://github.com/claimsforce-gmbh/flutter-segment to your project to instrument your App. Segment will bundle the Amplitude SDK if added as destination.